# Русские буквы отображаются в printf огромными числами

Tags: c

Привет всем!

Нужно закодировать все буквы слова путём замены буквы на порядковый номер в алфавите.

Подскажите как "красиво" написать код?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[100];
    char chars[33] = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    printf("Vvedite slovo nige (ot 0 do 100 simvolov):\n");
    scanf("%s", word);
    printf("Zashifrovannoe slovo:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("%d", strchr(chars, word[i]) - chars + 1);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Пока получается вот такой вот "мусор"

```
Vvedite slovo nige (ot 0 do 100 simvolov):
абв
Zashifrovannoe slovo:
-11008307-11008307-11008307
```

Comment: Вы хорошо понимаете что именно выводите в `printf()`?

Comment: позицию буквы в алфавите

Comment: хорошо, и как можно найти индекс буквы в массиве char?

Comment: А что с этим индексом делать дальше? И ещё одна тонкость: в какой локали вы работаете? Если это UTF, то подход с char неверный в принципе.

Comment: нужно просто вывести последовательность этих индексов. вот и всё.

Comment: установка локали разве как-то повлияет?

Comment: конечно. в utf функции типа `strchr()` вообще неприменимы.

Comment: "спасибо" за помощь

Comment: @MadCat45: @klopp всё правильно сказал. Если вы думаете, что один char = одна буква, ваши знания устарели.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ловите

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h> // для CharToOem()

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char abc[] = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
  char abc866[sizeof(abc)];
  char line[256];

  /*
    Перекодируем, т.к. в винде ввод/вывод консоли в кодировке cp866, 
    а в остальных местах (в т.ч. и аргументы командной строки!!!) в cp1251
  */
  CharToOem(abc, abc866); 


  while (printf("> "), fflush(stdout), fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; line[i]; i++) {
      char *c = strchr(abc866, line[i]);
      printf("%d ", c ? c - abc866 + 1 : 0);
    }
    puts("");
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Что неопонятно, спрашивайте (для нотификации пишите в комментарии @user-nick)

Вариант 2 (для 2-х байтных utf-8, обозвал его **unix**, т.к. этот макросимвол также определен в Linux по умолчанию). Если не лениться, то легко обобщить (просто надо сделать "матрицу" алфавитов со строками, которые индексируются  длиной utf-8 символа (надеюсь, сам код подскажет, как это делать)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifndef unix
#include <windows.h> // для CharToOem()
#else
#include <string.h>
#endif

/*
  Проверяет является ли байт началом символа в UTF-8
  Возвращает 
  -1 - недопустимый символ (шаг назад)
  n > 0 UTF-8 символ длиной n байт
 */
int
utf8_chrlen (const char *utf)
{
  u_int ucs = *utf & 0xFF;

  if (ucs < 128)
    return 1;
  if ((ucs & 0xC0) == 0x80 || ucs == 0xFF || ucs == 0xFE) 
    return -1;

  int n = 5;
  while (n && (ucs & (1<<n)))
    n--;
  return 7-n;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char abc[] = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ",
    *pabc = abc, *c;
  char line[256];
  int chrlen = 2; // kludge только для "алфавита" из 2-х байтных utf8 букв 

#ifndef unix // предположим, что в *nix UTF-8 (это далеко не всегда так)
  /*
    Перекодируем, т.к. в винде ввод/вывод консоли в кодировке cp866, 
    а в остальных местах (в т.ч. и аргументы командной строки!!!) в cp1251
  */
  char abc866[sizeof(abc)];
  pabc = abc866;
  chrlen = 1;
  CharToOem(abc, abc866); 
#endif

  while (printf("> "), fflush(stdout), fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
    int i, step = 1;

    for (i = 0; line[i]; i += step) {
#ifndef unix      
      c = strchr(pabc, line[i]);
#else
      if ((step = utf8_chrlen(line + i)) < 1)
        step = 1;
      char buf[8];
      strncpy(buf, line + i, step);
      buf[step] = 0;
      c = strstr(pabc, buf);
#endif
      printf("%d ", c ? (c - pabc) / chrlen + 1 : 0);
    }
    puts("");
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Функции для UTF-8 и Unicode (ASCII&Cyrillic), независимые от setlocale() можно посмотреть в [ucsutf.c](http://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW) (заголовочный файл к ним [ucsutf.h](http://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL)).

---

Еще одним решением может быть хэш-таблица (utf8:index) для используемых utf-8 символов (вместо "матрицы"), которая заполняется при просмотре `abc[]`.

Хотя, возможно лучшим выходом (безусловно, зависит от задачи) вообще станет переход к UCS32.

Comment: "*а в остальных местах*" - например, в исходнике :-)

Comment: @klopp, ага, в файлах, в т.ч. в исходнике.

Comment: Ну, в VS исходники запросто в UTF будут. Во всяком случае в 2010 - по умолчанию.

Comment: @klopp, серьезно? Ну, я в винде не пишу, а с UTF алфавитом  сейчас в Linux попробую.

Comment: У меня XP в virtualbox крутится :) Правда, задумался: действительно ли по умолчанию, или я где-то настраивал... Вот не помню. Но сейчас VS в UTF всё делает, так что нужно проверять в любом случае в какой кодировке исходник.

Comment: @klopp, добавил "ленивый" вариант с 2-х байтными (а это все русские) utf-8 буквами.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить

```
printf("%d", strchr(chars, word[i]) - chars + 1);
```

На

```
printf("%c", strchr(chars, word[i]) - chars + 1);
```

Comment: А какой смысл выражение `указатель - указатель - 1` приводить к char?

Comment: выводит артефакты %%%♥%%

Comment: вообще strchr(chars, word[i]) - chars не слишком понятно, что должно показывать. chars - массив, значит вы вычитаете указатель. т.е. 16ричное значение адреса начала массива в памяти. отсюда и отрицательные числа.

Comment: можно разименовать указатель  strchr(chars, word[i]) и вывести это значение через спецификатор (так кажется оно называется) %c. Т.е. char c = strchr(chars, word[i]);  printf("%c", c*)

Comment: `char c = strchr(chars, word[i]);` - лучше вообще ничего не пишите, чем такое.

Comment: кай, уже отвык от с)) но суть понятна

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i = i + 1)
> ```

Не надо считать длину в цикле. Она так вычисляется (с полным проходом по строке!) для каждого символа. Ну и инкремент лучше записывать по-человечески.

```
for (int i = 0; word[i]; ++i)
```

> Пока получается вот такой вот "мусор"

Потому что strchr не находит символ в строке и возвращает 0. Потом ты из него вычитаешь адрес и добавляешь 1.

Почему не находит? Скорее всего из-за того, что у тебя исходник в win1251, а консоль работает в oem866, из-за чего коды не совпадают.

Answer (score 0):

С английскими символами поколдовал, получилось такое решение

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    char chars[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char * c;
    char word[100];
    scanf("%s", word);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        c = strchr(chars, word[i]);
        printf("%d ", *c - ('a') + 1);
    }
}
```

Но с русскими так не получится, их по умолчанию нет в ASCII, которой пользуется С. Найдёте решения проблемы с символами и будет вам счастье:)